# Making a battery-management addition for my laptop

Tags: python, linux, bios, acpi

Considering to attempt to write something which would enable 'conservation mode' in Linux for my lenovo laptop. Maybe as an addition to the TLP-battery management software.

Question.

I'm a novice, although I have a couple of courses in programming, it will require a lot of tinkering and try and fail. Is it possible or probable that I could damage my laptop when writing such software?

Comment: Depends on how deep you want to dive in. Do you want to use linux commands? Or hack the battery management firmware or the TLP?

Comment: Haven't thought much about how. I observe that TLP has a kernel module for thinkpad, enabling conservation mode. At any rate my hunch is I have to write something accessing acpi, which to some degree has specificity depending on computer. I suppose it will require exploration, try and fail, before I get it right. I'm probably asking if I can brick my computer tinkering with acpi tables. Hope I'm formulating the right question.

Comment: So explore. You have to read some specs, maybe start with ACPI specs. If you are mainly interested in if you could break your hardware it is important if there are fallback or emergency modes, e.g. are you able to turn on the fan for good or will it come back on at some point due to a hardware emergency mode that you can't control and that will override your changes. Usually there are low level self-protection states for hardware that are embedded in the firmware.